# How to create a 2 way highway in Sumo

Tags: sumo

How to create a 2 way highway in Sumo? like cars going from one direction and the other cars coming from another direction? All the examples I see are 1 way highway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in netedit [enable two-way-mode](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Netedit/editModesNetwork.html#creating_two-way_roads). In XML just add another edge going from the second node to the first (you can do this manually in netedit as well of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have Netedit version 1.11.0 that hasn't tow way mode option.

Comment: It definitely has. It is the rightmost button in the create mode with the two red arrows